# triggering function on another page via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

On our website we are loading an IIFE script from a third party that checks for a certain url parameter and sets a cookie. On another page I want to set that parameter with out redirecting the user, reloading the page or tampering with the third parties code.

The reason I want to do things this way is because the third party sets data only from the url parameters, typically users navigate to the site via a link from social media or elsewhere and the parameter is predefined (ie: example.com/?color=red). However we want customers to be able to select the parameter that is being set by the third party code. A possible solution I have come up with is via an ajax $.get request however this is not working.

To get a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish here is the whole process simplified:

at example.com

```
(function(){

function run_this(){
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const fav_color = urlParams.get('color');
    document.cookie = 'customer_fav_color=testing that we can set colors through a GET request - customer color is '+ fav_color;
}


run_this();
})();
```

on example.com/cart

```
 var fav_color = 'blue';
    var color_xhr = $.get('https://example.com',{color: fav_color}
         ).done(function(data, status, xhr){
              // do something here
         });
```

Any ideas why this would not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage or sessionStorage to store shared parameter beetwen tabs and get notify for new changes by set a timer to check this parameter with setInterval.

Comment: the code setting the cookie is not my own, its from a third party.